# How to call an external REST API in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, rest, proxy, httpwebrequest, silverlight-5.0

Assuming I don't control the server and can't put a crossdomain.xml or clientaccesspolicy.xml file there, how can I make http calls inside a Silverlight app to an external REST API, without having to use javascript to do it and then pass the data to the Silverlight app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing an ASP.NET proxy similar to what's described [here](http://kiwigis.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/how-to-create-simple-proxy-in-aspnet.html)

and then adding the following code to the Silverlight App:

```
    public class Handler : IWebRequestCreate
    {
        public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
        {
            return WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(new Uri("http://localhost:3234/Proxy.ashx?" + Uri.EscapeUriString(uri.OriginalString)));
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        HttpWebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", new Handler());
        HttpWebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", new Handler());

        (...rest of code...)
    }
```

One caveat is that on the rest of the code one must be carefull to always use `HttpWebRequest.Create` and never `HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp`

Comment: I wish you can complete this code and exemplified the rest of code. @Gustavo

Answer (score 0):

You can build up your own proxy server (or server application, or http handler in your web app) to forward requests to the desired host.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way, either you use **crossdomain.xml** and **clientaccesspolicy.xml** or you solve this with **javascript** passing data to the app.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, a proxy server is about the only answer because of the restriction that Microsoft built in from the ground up. I've been working with Silverlight for years and wish that they'd never done that.

But, I created this library:
https://bitbucket.org/MelbourneDeveloper/restclient-.net

It has an implementation of a pass through (proxy) REST service which talks to BitBucket along with a Silverlight sample which makes it look as though the client app in Silverlight is talking directly to BitBucket. I have included the code in the sample that serves up a clientaccesspolicy for you.